# Symlink to random cat image

Tags: filesystems, symlink

Say I had a folder full of cat images. I'd like to create a symlink that points to a random cat from that folder and changes each time the symlink is accessed.

I suppose I could create a script that is constantly re-assigning the symlink to a different random cat image at N intervals. Could be a bit more ideal to only change it each time the symlink is accessed. Is there any simple way to get an on-accessed event for a sym-link to trigger some code?

Comment: If you're using Linux, there's [`incron`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Incron#Incrontab_format)

Comment: I am on Linux and that looks like exactly what I need :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a symlink, you could use an alias, which does not require constant updating of the file path:

```
alias random-cat='sxiv "$(ls <path/to/images/*> | shuf | head -1)"'
```

This will list out all your images, shuffle them in random order and pick the first random result to be opened in an image viewer.

Replace `sxiv` with your preferred image viewer.

This can be added to your `~/.bashrc` and be executed from anywhere in the terminal. Or you could simply add the command line inside the single quotes to a script.

Comment: This is a good solution. My needs personally though call for a symlink as the software I want to pull random cat images can only be configured to handle a valid filepath, so an executable script or alias won't do.